# mongoose Model.save() only returns { _id, __v }

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I know this question has been asked before but I feel like I'm doing everything right and I'm still having an issue. I want to save an item from a form into my mongodb collection using mongoose.

My schema:

```js
// stationmodel.js
export const StationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   "FDID": String,
   "Fire dept name": String,
   "HQ addr1": String,
   "HQ city": String,
   "HQ state": String,
   "HQ zip": Number,
   "HQ phone": String,
   "Dept Type": String,
   "Organization Type": String,
   "Website": String,
   "Number Of Stations": Number,
   "Primary agency for emergency mgmt": Boolean,
}, {collection: "FEMA_stations"})
```

In my express app:

```js
// in routes.js
const StationSchema =  require('./stationmodel')
const Station = mongoose.model('Station', StationSchema, 'FEMA_stations')

const addstation = (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body)
   const newStation = new Station(req.body)
   newStation.save( function(err){
      if (err) { console.error(err) }
      console.log('newStation after save', newStation)
   })
}

const routes = app => {
  app.route('/api/addstation')
    .post(addstation)
}

export default routes
```

```js
// in index.js
import routes from './routes'

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
routes(app)
```

In my front end code, calling to the backend in a redux action:

```js
fetch('/api/addstation', {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(stationToAdd)
})
```

When I `console.log(req.body)` on my back end, I get the data I'm expecting.  It looks something like this:

```js
{
  FDID: '202020',
  'Fire dept name': 'Some Fire Department',
  'HQ addr1': 'Some address',
  'HQ city': 'San Dimas',
  'HQ state': 'CA',
  'HQ zip': 99999,
  'HQ phone': '5555555555',
  'Dept Type': 'Career',
  'Organization Type': 'State',
  Website: '',
  'Number Of Stations': 0,
  'Primary agency for emergency mgmt': true,
}
```

But when I `console.log` my `newStation` that I'm trying to `.save()`, all I get is a response like this:

```js
{ _id: 5efe29911ea067248f3c39a0, __v: 0 }
```

I know other people had issues with their schema, their model, making sure that they're truly connected to their mongodb collection, or making sure that the request is made with the `application/json` header, but I feel I have all those things right.  The code was pieced together from a much more modularized app to try to cut the fat and present the core issue, so let me know if I'm missing any glaring information.

What might be going wrong here?  Why is the data from `req.body` not making it into my new document that I'm trying to save to the collection?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: You might be looking for `console.log('newStation after save', newStation.toObject())`

Comment: Mmmm no, that changes nothing.  I am still not seeing all the properties from my `req.body` show up in my newly created `Station`.  I appreciate you linking those other posts, but they don't answer my question. They are concerned with filtering out unwanted properties.  My question is more about why my `req.body` is not making it into my new document.  I'll edit my question but I would really appreciate if you could open it back up

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that the data doesn't get saved correctly, I thought you only were concerned about the data not being visible in the log.

Comment: No worries, thanks for opening it back up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing es6 module `import/export` with Node.js CommonJS `require`.

In `stationmodel.js` You are using a "named export"

```
export const StationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(...
```

But in `routes.js` you are using CommonJS `require`

```
const StationSchema =  require('./stationmodel')
```

Which is likely to be an empty object. So the following line will create a model with an "empty" schema

```
const Station = mongoose.model('Station', StationSchema, 'FEMA_stations')
```

## The solution

use named `import` instead

```
import { StationSchema } from './stationmodel'
```

**TIP:**

Since you are already name the file `stationmodel.js`, which suggests it's a model. You can put the following in `stationmodel.js` directly to prevent the model from getting incorrect schema

```
export const Station = mongoose.model('Station', StationSchema, 'FEMA_stations')
```

Comment: Wow.  So much frustration for something so silly.  Thank you so much.  I'll reward the bounty as soon as SO allows.